# WatchKit - Do i need to register Apple Watch app in developer center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I have an iPhone app, which was already registered in the apple dev center.

In the project target I've added an Apple Watch app.

But when I'm running the app from Xcode on actual device it says:

```
You have a valid iOS Development certificate in the Member Center, but
it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on
another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import
it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate and
request a new one.
```

My current exported certificate doesn't allow usage of both iPhone and Watch apps. What do i do?

Thank you guys !

Comment: Is your certificate installed?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes quite some time ago. Sorry I got carried away. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html
```

Looks like you haven't downloaded the certificate to your machine...

Also need to register your Watch with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

For testing in watch you need to add watch UDID to developer centre.

And also you need to create Profiles for watch extention and Watch App.

I mean you need to create 3 Profiles(Development / Provisioning)

1. iPhone App
2. Extention
3. Watch app